PMSessionValidatePrintSettings never change on macOS
PMSessionValidatePrintSettings return always "false" on macOS
PMPrintSettings settings;
PMPrintSession session;
Boolean result;

PMCreateSession(&session);
PMSessionSetCurrentPMPrinter(session, printer);
PMCreatePrintSettings(&settings);
PMSessionDefaultPrintSettings(session, settings);
PMSetDuplex(settings, kPMDuplexTumble);
PMSessionValidatePrintSettings(session, settings, &result);

PMRelease(session);
PMRelease(settings);
    
if (result) NSLog (@"%@", @"changed");
    else NSLog (@"%@", @"not changed");

Thanks

Tip: Check the return values of the functions.

Tip: Read the documentation of PMSessionValidatePrintSettings.

Is it a problem if the print settings are ok and don't change in PMSessionValidatePrintSettings?

I need to detect it, if true duplex is supported...

I would expect false if duplex is supported and nothing changes. I don't know if the printer driver validates the settings or if it is a general, printer-independent validation. Have you tried printers that do and do not support duplex?

I found https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/81188, I think this method is bugged, do you know another way to detect if printer support duplex ?
